# Emulated Google/IDP Authentication Throwing Cross-Origin Frame Error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

In my web Firebase project, I am using `signInWithPopup` to sign in via Google. This works perfectly fine in production. When emulating Google authentication in development, though, the popup comes up, asks me for mock user details, I enter them but when I press submit, a cross-origin error occurs:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:9099" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

This error appears in the popup's console, NOT in my web app. I am not sure what could be causing this error. Here is the command that I am using to emulate auth:

```
firebase emulators:start --only "functions,firestore,auth"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: I believe this is a bug and have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/2873) to fix it.